# Use 'LEFT' formula in vba?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Does anyone know how to use the left formula in a temporary workbook.

e.g `=LEFT(B5,5)`

How would I be able to use this formula in vba?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much the same as with a regular formula

```
leftPart = Left(Range("B5"), 5)
```

Comment: + 1 One more way `Debug.Print Evaluate("=LEFT(B5,5)")`